# Longest visible arc I can safely make with an alarm clock transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, arc

So I have an audio frequency transformer that turns standard US 120V power into two seperate 9V circuits:

[image]
[image]
[image: 3]]

I got it from an alarm clock and want to create an arc with it, by turning it around and having the low voltage side as my input.  I have half a dozen 9V batteries, however I don't have any transistors that are rated for more than 5V, so turning any higher voltage into AC for the transformer would likely be challenging. I have plenty of resistors from 220 Ohms to 10 MOhms, so I was wondering if it would be feasible to hook the low end up to a household AC supply with lots of resistors to limit the amperage and not burn out the wires. Clearly I don't know a lot about circuitry, so I figured I should ask someone else before I go accidentally setting my transformer on fire. Would that feasibly work in any way? Is there some other better way to get a high voltage out of this, without me having to buy a bunch of materials?  Thanks.
*edit MOhms not kOhms

Comment: "Clearly I don't know a lot about circuitry" and playing with mains circuitry don't go together well! **DON'T DO THAT** you may **kill yourself** (NO KIDDING!). Playing with mains voltages demands respect and knowledge. Start your experience in electronics with low-voltage AND low-power circuits. Play with mains only when you reach a REAL understanding of what you are doing!!!

Comment: Find a local meetup group in your area where you can work with others skilled at this kind of thing. Any voltage sufficient to make interesting arcs in the air is usually _also_ quite dangerous. (This is NOT always true, but mostly true and mostly mostly especially true when you "don't know a lot about circuitry.") And can emit radiation. Find advice and help. As some motivation to make a serious effort to find a helpful group in your local area, you can look here for example: https://youtu.be/fSI8raTrbmA Do NOT do this ignorantly and without help. Experienced help mitigates your risks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. If you hooked 120v AC to the primary side of the transformer you would get ~1600v out the other end. This is a dangerously high voltage for a beginner to be playing with. In the past couple of years multiple young men have died doing things like this. IIRC one was tinkering with a computer power supply and another was building a jacobs ladder in his garage.

You should probably be starting out experimenting with circuits powered by low voltage DC power supplies: AA batteries, 9v batteries, low voltage AC-DC wall adapters, adjustable bench power supplies.

Also, 1600v won't get you a very big spark gap, less than a millimeter even.

Comment: You wouldn't get 1600V for long, if it all. It would just destroy the transformer and start a small fire.

Comment: @pericynthion Would it would burn out even if I got the 120V AC current down very low, to perhaps a few milliamps or even less? I have plenty of resistors; they are all rated for 1 watt, so the power through them shouldn't be an issue on any resistors above 20kohms (and I can always hook the resistors in parallel if I want a higher current w/out burnouts).  Will voltage alone fry the transistor without a lot of current?

Comment: You wouldn't get 1600v, transformers don't work like that. A 120v AC winding **cannot** support more than that without the transformer melting.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run a transformer 'backwards' and have it do what you hoped in your question.

Each winding of a transformer has a maximum voltage given by the size of the core and the number of turns. A 120v AC winding will not support more than that (well, maybe 10%, 20% more for tolerances) but not 10x more.

If you put the transformer backwards, and use resistors on the 9v winding to drop the wall power down, you will find the 9v winding runs at just that, and the 120v winding at 120v. If you leave out the resistors, you'll get an arc, but it will be the supply fuse going, or your transformer if you've bypassed the fuse.

Answer (score 0):

To simply, answer the question in your title, the dielectric breakdown of air is around 3 MV/m (3 million volts per meter).

So 120 volts **DC** would need a gap of no more than 120/3000000 m, or 0.04mm.

With 120V**AC**, the peak is 168V, so the gap could be as much as 168/3000000 m or 0.056mm, or 56um. Not much to see here.

Even if you push the transformer up to 240VAC, still too small to see with naked eye.

What you want is 20,000 volts or more. Look up "Tesla coil".